# Trouble sub-setting data.frame/not meaningful for factors error

Tags: r, subset

Sorry, I feel like this question has been asked but I've tried multiple of the solutions on this site and it still isn't working for me. I'm likely missing something.

I have a data.frame with 300 obs and 4 variables. One variable is "day" for number of days (1-300) I'm trying to make a subset of this data including everything before the nth day. I've included all of my code just in case I did something incorrectly. I initially took a transformed subset from a larger subset. Here's the beginning of my code

```
    Data <- data.frame(t(Original.data[1:4,]))
    colnames(Data) <-c("ID","day","Week","SD")
```

next line is just to creative a repeating ID number

```
    Data[,1] <- Data[1,4]
```

finally, sub-setting my data based on day. Here's everything I've tried

```
    New.Data <- Data[ which(Data$day<279),]
```

gives '<' not meaningful for factors error

```
    New.Data <- Data[1:Data$day<'279']
```

I've also tried this w/o the quotations and get the same "numerical expression has 328 elements: only the first used" error. The result is an empty data.frame

Thank you, and I apologize if this is a simple Q, I'm still new to R.

EDIT: I'm including what a sample of what my data looks like

```
    v    ID  day  Week  SD
    V1   1   -14  -2    23
    V2   2   2    1     54
    .    .   .    .     .
    .    .   .    .     .
    V56  52  279  39    42
    .    .   .    .     .
    .    .   .    .     .
    V300 350 325 44    48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R seems to be suggesting that Data$day is a factor variable rather than number. Try `typeof(Data$day)` to see what R thinks that it is.

Convert it first to a character and then to a numeric using:

```
Data$day <- as.numeric(as.character(Data$day))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, when I convert to numeric the values of day changes.

Comment: Ah, right. If it's a factor it will return that value. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the column of day is a numeric vector. For example you can do this:

```
 Data$day <- as.numeric(as.character(Data$day))
```

Then try

```
 New.Data <- Data[ which(Data$day<279),]
```

Let me know if this helps! :)

Comment: Just saw that Adam posted the same thing. Yes, try what Adam and I said and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you!, I tried and came up with another issue! See my other response to Adam

Comment: Ahhh yes! as.character is needed! Completely forgot about that!